# How to show latest dates for every user and filter rows if datediff between previous & last date < 7

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have below table structure

```
UserID | Date
1        2020-01-01
1        2020-01-02
1        2020-01-03
1        2020-02-05
1        2020-02-06
1        2020-03-08
1        2020-03-09
2        2020-02-03
2        2020-02-05
2        2020-02-06
3        2020-02-12
3        2020-02-13
3        2020-03-25
3        2020-03-26
```

Desired result:

```
UserID | Date
1       2020-03-08
1       2020-03-09
2       2020-02-03
2       2020-02-05
2       2020-02-06
3       2020-03-25
3       2020-03-26
```

So I need to show latest dates for every user and hide rows if datediff between previous & last date  < 7

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

I understand the you want the last 7 days of data per user. If so, you can use window functions:

```
select userid, date
from (
    select t.*, max(date) over(partition by userid) max_date
    from mytable t
) t
where datediff(day, date, max_date) <= 7
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b32895727b4b0654085f9dc1df6e937a)**:

```
userid | date      
:----- | :---------
1      | 2020-03-08
1      | 2020-03-09
2      | 2020-02-03
2      | 2020-02-05
2      | 2020-02-06
3      | 2020-03-25
3      | 2020-03-26
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for help. Not only the data for last 7 days but all data if previous date and next date have difference  less than 7 days. So for example for user 1 if we have data for him for whole April I need to display it.

Comment: @RomuloSQL: I don't know exactly what you mean by that... and this is not showing in your sample data (you can see that my query is producing the same resultset that you showed).

Comment: so for example user 4 have records from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-05 and also have records from 2020-02-23 to 2020-03-31. Let's assume user 4 doesn't have records from 2020-03-02 to 2020-03-05. I need to display all available records for user 4  in 2020-02-23 to 2020-03-31 (because it's last date period) period because the day difference from 2020-03-02 to 2020-03-05 where we don't have any records < 7. Hope now it's more clear. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @RomuloSQL: it is not a good practice to substiantially modify the question after answers were posted. And you can see that comments are not really meant to provide sample data (formatting is too poor). I would suggest [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), providing sample data and expected results that better represent your use case, and more details on the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of using two With clause statements as mentioned below.

With Date1 as(
 select userid,date
from
(
select userif, date,
rank() over(partition by userid order by date desc) as rnk
from table)A
where A.rnk=1)

With Date2 as (
select userid,date
  from (
select userid, date,,
rank  () over (partition by userid order by date desc) as rnk
from table )B 
   where B.rnk = 2)

select date1.userid,date1.date from
date1 join date2 on
date1.userid=date2.userid
where DATEDIFF (date1.date,date2.date) <7